# How to get all files of particular date modified from a folder with numerous files of different date ?using java code

Tags: java, file, automation

> Blockquote

I want to filter the files according to its date and time ,but i couldn't find any method in java .
please help if any one has any idea about it.`File fil =new File("C:\sujeet\efsfiles\iems\input");
    FilenameFilter filter =new FilenameFilter(){
     public boolean accept(File fil, String name){

```
 return name.
}};
File[] temp= fil.listFiles(filter);
public void SeeFiles(){
for(File file : temp){

 if(file.isFile())  {
    count++;
     System.out.println(file.getName());


 }`
```

Comment: *but i couldn't find any method in java*. Where did you look?

Comment: thanks ,please comment if u know any method?

Comment: Where did you look to confirm that there is no such method?

Comment: FilenameFilter filter =new FilenameFilter(){
  public boolean accept(File fil, String name){ 
     
  return name.
 }};

Comment: there is no method in FilenameFilter to filter the file with date modified

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNameFilter` here won't work as you are looking for the file attribute level

Check this can be any help

```
package com.tmp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Tmp implements DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Path dir = Paths.get( "d:\\tmp" ); // Folder to search for files

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream( dir, new Tmp() )) {

            for ( Path entry : stream ) {

                System.out.println( entry.getFileName() ); // file name which matched the accessed date
            }

        } catch ( IOException x ) {

            System.err.println( x );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept( Path file ) throws IOException {

        try {

            BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes( file, BasicFileAttributes.class );

            Date fileLastAccessedDate = new Date( attr.lastModifiedTime().toMillis() );

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.setTime( fileLastAccessedDate );

            cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
            cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
            cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
            cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM-dd-yyyy" );

            Date targetDate = sdf.parse( "2-20-2017" ); // date looking for the files

            return ( cal.getTime().equals( targetDate ) );

        } catch ( Exception x ) {

            System.err.println( x );

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```